# Three shooters shoot a target

Tags: probability

Three shooters shoot a target. The known probability to hit the target of the first, second and third shooter are 0.3, 0.4 and 0.5 respectively. What is the probability that the target is hit from **only** one shooter?

I try this.

The probabilities that two will not heat the target:

0.7 x 0.6 = 0.42
0.7 x 0.5 = 0.35
0.6 x 0.5 = 0.30

and finally I'm not sure what should i do with those results? suppose have to multiply them?

Comment: Can you calculate the probability that the first shooter hit the target and the other don't? You should easily arrive to the result.

Comment: How many ways there are that only 1 of them hit it? What are the probabilities for each of those outcomes? Multiply the probability of one of them hitting and the other 2 missing for each case.

Answer (score 7):

Split it into **disjoint** events, and then add up their probabilities:

- The probability that the target is hit by the 1st shooter only is $\small(0.3)\times(1-0.4)\times(1-0.5)$
- The probability that the target is hit by the 2nd shooter only is $\small(1-0.3)\times(0.4)\times(1-0.5)$
- The probability that the target is hit by the 3rd shooter only is $\small(1-0.3)\times(1-0.4)\times(0.5)$

The overall probability is therefore:

$$\small(0.3)\times(1-0.4)\times(1-0.5)+(1-0.3)\times(0.4)\times(1-0.5)+(1-0.3)\times(1-0.4)\times(0.5)=0.44$$

Answer (score 7):

Let 3 shoots A, B and C.

$P(A) = 0.3, P(A') = 1 - 0.3 = 0.7$

$P(B) = 0.4, P(B') = 1 - 0.4 = 0.6$

$P(C) = 0.5, P(C') = 1 - 0.5 = 0.5$

Probability of hitting by only one = $P(A) \times P(B') \times P(C') + P(B) \times P(C') \times P(A') + P(C) \times P(A') \times P(B')$

$= 0.3 \times 0.6 \times 0.5 + 0.4 \times 0.5 \times 0.7 + 0.5 \times 0.7 \times 0.6$

$= 0.09 + 0.14 + 0.21 = 0.44$

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer

Comment: Mine pleasure. And I saw your questions. You not accept any answer in your all questions. I think you have to accept the answers (use tick). Because in future if anyone have similar problem. They get help from your questions easily.

Comment: @KanwaljitSingh why can't we use inclusion-exclusion here? 
$P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A,B) - P(A,C) - P(B,C) + P(A,B,C)$ ?